# Checkbox labels appear under the checkbox (even with no styles loaded)

Tags: vue-formulate

How to fix the default (no styles) checkbox labels that appear under the box (it should be to the right of the box like in the example)

[image]

I'm using tailwind and styling the form through the global string option.  Everything worked great so far until I tried styling checkboxes.  The issue being that the label is showing beneath the box, and even if I remove all styles (as show in the screenshot) this is still and issue.  I don't know how to target this label with the global string option, this is the structure I've been working on, trying to style label>box and input>box to get the label beside the checkbox.

```
Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
    classes: {
        outer: 'py-4',
        wrapper(context) {
            switch (context.classification) {
                case "button":
                    return "";
                default:
                    return "bg-regal-blue-400 py-3  w-full hover:bg-regal-blue-500";
            }
        },
        label(context){
            switch (context.classification) {
                case "box":
                    return "bg-red-500";
                default:
                    return "w-full block text-gray-400 px-4 text-lg";
            }
        },
        element: 'w-full',
        input(context) {
            switch (context.classification) {
                case "button":
                    return "text-lg border-2 rounded-full h-12 bg-red-900 border-red-500 font-bold px-10 hover:bg-red-500 transition-colors duration-500 focus:outline-none";
                case "textarea":
                    return "bg-transparent w-full mt-2 h-48 focus:outline-none text-xl placeholder-gray-700 px-4";
                case "box":
                    return "h-6 w-6";
                default:
                    return "bg-transparent w-full h-10 focus:outline-none text-xl placeholder-gray-700 px-4";
            }
        },
        button: 'bg-red-500',
        help: '',
        errors: 'px-4',
        error: 'text-red-500'
    }
})
```

Even in some of the provided codebox examples, like "Tailwind via Config", if you add a checkbox to the existing form the labels appear under the checkboxes https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-vue-formulate-2-password-reset-all-global-kydyp

Comment: This demo doesn't appear to link to the correct place ‍♂️

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all that is missing is a `display: flex` on the wrapper when it's a box. Here's the code you provided for your configuration modified with a flex:

```js
Vue.use(VueFormulate, {
  classes: {
    outer: "py-4",
    wrapper(context) {
      switch (context.classification) {
        case "button":
          return "";
        case "box":
          return "w-full flex justify-start";
        default:
          return "bg-regal-blue-400 py-3  w-full hover:bg-regal-blue-500";
      }
    },
    label(context) {
      switch (context.classification) {
        case "box":
          return "bg-red-500 flex-grow";
        default:
          return "w-full block text-gray-400 px-4 text-lg";
      }
    },
    element ({ classification }) {
      switch (classification) {
        case 'box':
          return 'px-1';
        default:
          return 'w-full';
      }
    },
    input(context) {
      switch (context.classification) {
        case "button":
          return "text-lg border-2 rounded-full h-12 bg-red-900 border-red-500 font-bold px-10 hover:bg-red-500 transition-colors duration-500 focus:outline-none";
        case "textarea":
          return "bg-transparent w-full mt-2 h-48 focus:outline-none text-xl placeholder-gray-700 px-4";
        case "box":
          return "h-6 w-6";
        default:
          return "bg-transparent w-full h-10 focus:outline-none text-xl placeholder-gray-700 px-4";
      }
    },
    button: "bg-red-500",
    help: "",
    errors: "px-4",
    error: "text-red-500"
  }
});
```

And here's a link to an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-vue-formulate-checkbox-after-pwxh2?file=/src/main.js